# get user movement on screen by touch listener but having an issue that the conditions are called numerous time

Tags: java, android

```
I want to get user finger location on screen so
```

that to perform some actions like increase the volume when 
the user moves her finger upward but the problem I am facing that 
the code I want to run on user upward movement calls many times
 the even user just place her finger on screen any one can help me

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
                downXValue = event.getX();
                downYValue = event.getY();
                Log.d("recording", "= " + downYValue);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                // Get the X value when the user released his/her finger
                float currentX = event.getX();
                float currentY = event.getY();
                // check if horizontal or vertical movement was bigger

                if (Math.abs(downXValue - currentX) > Math.abs(downYValue
                        - currentY)) {
                    Log.d("recording", "x");
                    // going backwards: pushing stuff to the right
                    if (downXValue < currentX) {
                        Log.d("recording", "right");

                    }

                    // going forwards: pushing stuff to the left
                    if (downXValue > currentX) {
                        Log.d("recording", "left");

                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d("recording", "y ");

                    if (downYValue < currentY) {
                        Log.d("recording", "down");




                        }
                    }
                    if (downYValue > currentY) {
                        Log.d("recording", "up");




                    }
                }
                break;
            }

        }

        return true;

    }


});
```

any one give me good suggestions that what should I do

Answer (score 1):

*CUSTOME GESTURE LISTENER*

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;


public class SimpleGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final String TAG = "SimpleGestureListener";
    private Listener mListener;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        Log.i(TAG,e1.toString()+"\n"+e2.toString());
        Log.d(TAG,"distanceX = "+distanceX+",distanceY = "+distanceY);
        if (mListener == null)
            return true;

        if (distanceX == 0 && Math.abs(distanceY) > 1){
            mListener.onScrollVertical(distanceY);
        }

        if (distanceY == 0 && Math.abs(distanceX) > 1){
            mListener.onScrollHorizontal(distanceX);
        }
        return true;
    }


    public void setListener(Listener mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    interface Listener{
        /**
         * left scroll dx >0
         * right scroll dx <0
         * @param dx
         */
        void onScrollHorizontal(float dx);

        /**
         * upward scroll dy > 0
         * downward scroll dy < 0
         * @param dy
         */
        void onScrollVertical(float dy);
    }
}
```

## USAGE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private GestureDetector mDetector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SimpleGestureListener simpleGestureListener = new SimpleGestureListener();
        simpleGestureListener.setListener(new SimpleGestureListener.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollHorizontal(float dx) {
                Log.i(TAG,"horizontal = " +dx);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollVertical(float dy) {
                Log.i(TAG,"vertical = " +dy);
            }
        });
        mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, simpleGestureListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

You can use the above code in your application to track:

1. left-right swipe
2. top-down swipe

Comment: same is the case with my code the code code i want to run on user movement call many times

Comment: using your code the conditions call almost about 6 to 7 times on just a swipe

Comment: and in my case i want to apply the user finger movement on 2 different layouts on same acctivity and perform different tasks

Comment: It will be called even if there is a minute change in finger position because there is a change in x and y coordinates of the touch.You need to give a threshold  value and check if the distance exceed that value, you need to call the appropriate method

Comment: but what if i have 2 relative layout on activity and want to perform 2 different tasks on user scroll

Comment: You can have different views on each of the places and set a touchlistener on those view and just pass the MotionEvent object to  the CustomListener Object

Comment: i want to increase volume when user scroll upward on right side of the screen and increase or decrease brightness when user sscoll on left side of the screen

Comment: Then your CustomListner will be a bit complicated.You need to check the dimension of the layout and if the x coordinate is within the left-half of the layout, you fire the left scroll method and if it is in right-half then fire the right scroll methis

Comment: i know its complicated that why i am asking question on stack overflow i am trying that for last 4 days but could not handle that

Comment: i use to differen t layouts on both side of the screen and perform the but same is the case the code calls many times and destory the working

Comment: No one will solve your problem.We can just guide you.I have mentioned all I could

Comment: just tell me how set these listeners on a specific layout

Comment: on 2 different layouts of same screen